# Fast Panorama Image Compositing

Tags: c++, opencv, blending, 360-panorama

I am working on a l**ive panorama algorithm on C++**. Basically, I took [Stitching_detailed.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) from OpenCV as reference and started to modify it according to my needs. I have been carefully studying the stitching pipeline on which it is based ( as detailed in [Images stitching by OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d46/group__stitching.html) and [Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features](http://Automatic%20Panoramic%20Image%20Stitching%20using%20Invariant%20Features) ).

My main problem now is the execution time. I tried to implement as much as I could in CUDA. However, I got some problems with the compositing block. It seems that there is [no CUDA implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7344) for the Graph Cut Seam Finder algorithm.

I am aiming to stitch the images from 6 different cameras in ~60 ms (~15FPS). However, in my current implementation the CPU Version of GraphCut Seam Finder takes about 90 ms for only 3 images ( being 0.1 MP each).

I have tried to use other Seam Finder algorithms which are less computationally expensive as Voronoi and DP, but unfortunately the result is an unpleasant stitched image.

I am kind of lost here now, what could I do in order to speed up this part? Are there any other seam_finding/blending techniques I could make use of?